# .mkv file is not open?

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 14.10 & install vlc player but when a. Mkv file is opened, it can not display the video, only voice can run. Video is buffered. Is there any player that can play mkv file?

Comment: VLC plays .mkv very well so there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The .mkv extension signifies just a [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format).  If the audio is playing but no video, chances are you do not have the right decoder installed for the video part.  A couple of debugging tips:

1. In VLC, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> (tools -> media information).
2. What is listed under Codec?

An example I have is:

```
Video: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Audio: Codec: A52 Audio (aka AC3) (a52 )
```

This data is necessary to post to help you more, but you may be able to figure it out with this alone.  It should give you data about what you can search for next at least.  Since VLC is kind of self contained, you may have to move on if it's not playing it right off the bat...

So, another option is to try mplayer:

```
sudo apt install mplayer
mplayer <file>
```

Comment: Video: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1) . but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "Smplayer", it seems to not have any issues playing any media format I have thrown at it for whatever reason.

[Here is a link](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) for the application. Give it a try and see if that helps. An older version is available in the software center. Hope it helps you.